# How to avoid passing a context down a bunch of method calls?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Suppose I have a problem that, intuitively, is best solved using recursion.

I'm also trying to use dependency injection to make code testeable:

```
class Foo {

    Bar bar;

    Foo(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    ResultType doFoo() {
        ...stuff...
        bar.doBar();
    }

}

class Bar {

    Baz baz;

    Bar(Baz baz) {
        this.baz = baz;
    }

    ResultType doBar() {
        ...stuff...
        baz.doBaz();
    }
}

class Baz {

    Foo foo;

    Baz(Foo foo) {
        this.foo;
    }

    ResultType doBaz() {
        if (foo is needed) {
            foo.doFoo(smaller problem)
        } else {
            ...stuf...
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if Baz wan't dependant on Foo, you could just do something like:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(new Bar(new Baz()));
```

Baz can take any Foo, so it is no problem if it just gets the one at the top, thus forming a loop.

(The JVM can take care of loops IIRC). Only Baz can determine if it needs Foo.

What is the cleanest way to get a Foo into Baz in a way that is testeable?

Is adding a `Foo` parameter to `doBaz()` my only option? (Implying that Foo needs to pass "this" to doBar, which then passes it to doBaz, etc... or is there a better way?)

**EDIT:**

Perhaps the problem description would indeed be useful.

The algorithm is basically a compiler, it takes code as input and outputs a datastructure representing the meaning of the code. This datastructure is highly recursive in nature.

However, it is possible that there may be unclarities in the code (think undeclared methods). What prompted this problem is that, unlike most compilers, this one should not simply vomit a bunch of errors at the user, but instead offer an option to the user to enter more code.

Basically, the compiler would then temporarily halt compiling the "main" code, and start a compilation on this new code provided by the user. After this, it will attach the resulting datastructure to the "main" datastructure.

If, inside this code provided by the user, there are more unclarities, it will again allow the user to clarify.

Basically, the component that realizes that the code is incomplete (reprezented by Baz) has to call the "main" component (Foo) to start the compilation of the code provided by the user.

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you described the actual problem in more detail. It's likely that there's a different decomposition that would be less cyclical.

Comment: Ok, done. It's just that the process itself is recursive in a way that is visible to the user, so perhaps getting rid of the recursive algorithm itself is hard.

Comment: I have a vague sense that a Visitor might be the better approach here.

Answer (score 0):

some other options:

1. if `Foo` is a singleton (i.e. there is going to be only one instance in the program), then you could have a static method in `Foo` returning such instance
2. you could maintain a reference to the "previous" object, and use it from Baz to traverse back:

   class Foo {

   ```
   Bar bar;

   Foo(Bar bar) {
       this.bar = bar;
       bar.setFoo(this);
   }

   ResultType doFoo() {
       ...stuff...
       bar.doBar();
   }
   ```

   }

   class Bar {
       Foo foo;
       Baz baz;

   ```
   Bar(Baz baz) {
       this.baz = baz;
       baz.setBar(this);
   }

   void setFoo(Foo foo) {
     this.foo = foo;
   }

   Foo getFoo() {
     return foo;
   }

   ResultType doBar() {
       ...stuff...
       baz.doBaz();
   }
   ```

   }

   class Baz {
       Bar bar;
       Foo foo;

   ```
   Baz(Foo foo) {
       this.foo;
   }

   void setBar(Bar bar) {
     this.bar = bar;
   }

   ResultType doBaz() {
       if (foo is needed) {
           bar.getFoo().doFoo(smaller problem)
       } else {
           ...stuf...
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

You could construct these objects seperately, and then register them with eachother.

The simplest form would look like this:

```
class Foo {

    Bar bar;

    void setBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    ResultType doFoo() {
        ...stuff...
        bar.doBar();
    }

}

class Bar {

    Baz baz;

    void setBaz(Baz baz) {
        this.baz = baz;
    }

    ResultType doBar() {
        ...stuff...
        baz.doBaz();
    }
}

class Baz {

    Foo foo;

    void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.foo;
    }

    ResultType doBaz() {
        if (foo is needed) {
            foo.doFoo(smaller problem)
        } else {
            ...stuf...
        }
    }
}
```

Then, build the system like this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Bar bar = new Bar();
Baz baz = new Baz();
foo.setBar(bar);
bar.setBaz(baz);
baz.setFoo(foo);
```

Then, to make it more robust, you could build it out with better exception handling if the necessary associations haven't been made. You might even make a factory method to create these objects together (as above) to help ensure that they aren't created incorrectly.

Comment: I ended up using a setter for the dependency only on Baz, but turns out that seems to be enough. I'd have preferred a compile-time check, but a runtime check is the next best thing I guess. Thanks for the suggestion.